# Does Install4j has support for Solaris 11.1 (Native SPARC and Zones) (64-bit)operating system

Tags: install4j

Does install4j has support for  Solaris 11.1 (Native SPARC and Zones) (64-bit)operating system.
I was trying to look at the install4j documentation.But could not find find this mentioned.

Thanks
sony

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Solaris is supported. In fact, install4j's Unix installers only need a working POSIX compatible shell, the installer does not include any native code.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you mean by "support". For deep support I would say that install4j would then have to be able to produce [IPS packages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/server-storage/solaris11/technologies/ips-323421.html) because this is the recommended way to install software on Solaris 11. However you can get by just fine without it so if install4j support a POSIX-shell method of installing software on Linux/Unix (e.g. Solaris) then that should be ok for the majority of use cases.